# Why wont my code work for a single list but works for a nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

The first print system work when there are multiple lists passed into the function.  However, when passing in only a single list, I get the error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pop'"

This code is attempting to remove one item from the list to see if that popped item still exists in the remaining list.

```
def check_row(p):
    for e in p:
        while e:
            x = e.pop()
            if x in e:
                return False
    return True


print check_row([[8,2,3,4,5],
              [2,3,1,5,6],
              [4,0,2,3,1]])

print check_row([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are popping the item from the *element*, not the outer list. If your elements are not lists, then don't try to treat them as such.

You cannot, however, remove items from the outer list while at the same time looping over it, and expect the loop to not jump items.

If you want to see if an item occurs more than once in the list, compare the length of the `set()` of the list instead:

```
def check_row(row):
    return len(row) == len(set(row))
```

This only works for hashable values, which nested lists are not, but at the very least does not alter the list in place, as your code would do.

You could still use a list scan, but then at least use `list.index()` to limit the search to a start index beyond the current position:

```
def check_row(row):
    for i, elem in enumerate(row):
        try:
            row.index(elem, i + 1)
            return False  # dupe found
        except ValueError:
            pass  # no dupe found
    return True
```

However, this assumes you wanted to only test the outer list for duplicates. Supporting a nested structure and flat structures in the same code without more details on what you expect to happen in each case is much more complicated.

Comment: I'm confused... Your example code will work fine for the flat list case, but not the nested list case since `list` aren't hashible...

Comment: @mgilson: darn, that is true; this'll only work for hashable values in the list.

Comment: @mgilson: however, I suspect the OP didn't mean to use this on nested lists, only discovering that the code doesn't work *unless* he uses nested lists.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't completely sure what OP actually is wanting to do here ... but I thought it might be worth pointing out.  And besides, it isn't every day I get to ask for clarification on an answer from the great Ninja himself.  :-P

Comment: @mgilson: there, added an inefficient 'scan' version that at least doesn't destroy the list in the process.

Comment: "You cannot, however, remove items from a list while at the same time looping over it, and expect the loop to not jump items." That's not true. First, he's removing from the right, which doesn't have that problem. Second, he's not iterating over the inner list at all, just looping `while` it's not empty.

Comment: @abarnert: there is an outer loop `for e in p:`.

Comment: What?!?  Since when did `list.index` start taking a second argument?  (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

to be fair, I tried it, and it does work...

Comment: Ahh, here it is:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Comment: @mgilson: See the [mutable sequence types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) documentation; only mutable sequences support the extra arguments. Interestingly enough, `tuple` supports the arguments as well!

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Not only mutable sequences ... `str` supports it too.  I suppose that only mutable sequences are *guaranteed* to support it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sure, but he's not removing elements from `p`, only from `e`, so that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a single (non-nested) list, you're calling `.pop()` on elements (`e`) which aren't lists and therefore presumably don't have a `.pop` method.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `e` is an element of your list. In the nested one, `e` is a list, while in the second one, `e` is an integer. Therefore, `e.pop` is invalid for the second one.

You'll have to make it always nested:

```
>>> print(check_row([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]))
True
```

This way, the value passed to check_row is always a nested list, even if it has only one element.

But as far as checking if the elements are still in the other lists, i would firstly flatten the list, and then check if there are duplicate elements in the list.

```
import collections
def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, str):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el

def check_row(p):
    flat = list(flatten(p))
    return len(flat) == len(set(flat))
```

This way, `check_row` will always produce the result you wanted, ignoring the fact it's a list or nested list :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing yourself with your naming. The function you called `check_row` actually checks a *list* of rows, despite the name, so passing it a single row fails. The fact that you're using meaningless one-letter names doesn't help either. Let's rewrite it more clearly:

If you want a function that checks a single row,

```
def check_rows(rows):
    for row in rows:
        while row:
            element = row.pop()
            if element in row:
                return False
    return True
```

Now it should be clearer why it fails: You're passing it a single `row` as the `rows`, so `for row in rows` is getting the elements rather than the rows, and it all goes downhill from there.

---

What you probably want is a `check_row` function that works on a single row, and then a `check_rows` that calls `check_row` on each row:

```
def check_row(row):
    while row:
        element = row.pop()
        if element in row:
            return False
    return True

def check_rows(rows):
    for row in rows:
        if not check_row(row):
            return False
    return True
```

---

But really, I don't know why you want this function at all. It destructively modifies the rows, removing every element up to the first duplicate. Why would you want that? For example, Martijn Pieters's solution is simpler and more efficient, as well as being non-destructive:

```
def check_row(row):
    return len(set(row)) == len(row)
```

And while we're at it, let's use the `all` function instead of an explicit loop for `check_rows`:

```
def check_rows(rows):
    return all(check_row(row) for row in rows)
```